# How do i remove the milliseconds from my timer

Tags: timer

I am making this game for school and I am trying to add a timer to levels. I have the timer working but not the way I want it to. It refreshes and it has milliseconds. I have searched every website for an answer but I can only find with dates and times or how do display them. I need the exact opposite.

```
package GameState;

import Main.GamePanel;
import TileMap.*;
import Entity.*;
import Entity.Enemies.*;
import Audio.AudioPlayer;
//timer imports
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Level1State extends GameState {

private TileMap tileMap;
private Background bg;
private static int cnt;
private Player player;

private ArrayList<Enemy> enemies;
private ArrayList<Explosion> explosions;

private HUD hud;

private AudioPlayer bgMusic;

public Level1State(GameStateManager gsm) {
    this.gsm = gsm;
    init();
}

public void init() {

    tileMap = new TileMap(30);
    tileMap.loadTiles("/Tilesets/grasstileset.gif");
    tileMap.loadMap("/Maps/level1-1.map");
    tileMap.setPosition(0, 0);
    tileMap.setTween(1);

    bg = new Background("/Backgrounds/grassbg1.2.jpg", 0.1);

    player = new Player(tileMap);
    player.setPosition(100, 100);

    populateEnemies();

    explosions = new ArrayList<Explosion>();

    hud = new HUD(player);

    bgMusic = new AudioPlayer("/Music/level1-1.mp3");
    bgMusic.play();

}

private void populateEnemies() {

    enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();

    Slugger s;
    Point[] points = new Point[] {
        new Point(200, 100), 
        new Point(860, 200),
        new Point(1525, 200),
        new Point(1680, 200),
        new Point(1800, 200)
    };
    for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        s = new Slugger(tileMap);
        s.setPosition(points[i].x, points[i].y);
        enemies.add(s);
    }

}

public void update() {

    // update player
    player.update();
    tileMap.setPosition(
        GamePanel.WIDTH / 2 - player.getx(),
        GamePanel.HEIGHT / 2 - player.gety()
    );

    // set background
    bg.setPosition(tileMap.getx(), tileMap.gety());

    // attack enemies
    player.checkAttack(enemies);

    // update all enemies
    for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
        Enemy e = enemies.get(i);
        e.update();
        if(e.isDead()) {
            enemies.remove(i);
            i--;
            explosions.add(
                new Explosion(e.getx(), e.gety()));
        }
    }

    // update explosions
    for(int i = 0; i < explosions.size(); i++) {
        explosions.get(i).update();
        if(explosions.get(i).shouldRemove()) {
            explosions.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }

}

public void draw(final Graphics2D g) {

    // draw bg
    bg.draw(g);

    // draw tilemap
    tileMap.draw(g);

    // draw player
    player.draw(g);

    // draw enemies
    for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
        enemies.get(i).draw(g);
    }

    // draw explosions
    for(int i = 0; i < explosions.size(); i++) {
        explosions.get(i).setMapPosition(
            (int)tileMap.getx(), (int)tileMap.gety());
        explosions.get(i).draw(g);
    }

    // draw hud
    hud.draw(g);

      ActionListener actListner = new ActionListener() {              
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {               
             cnt += 1;               
             g.drawString("Counter = "+cnt, 120, 120);               
          }              
      };         
       Timer timer = new Timer(1000, actListner);            
       timer.start();   
}

public void keyPressed(int k) {
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) player.setLeft(true);
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) player.setRight(true);
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_UP) player.setUp(true);
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) player.setDown(true);
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_W) player.setJumping(true);
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_E) player.setGliding(true);
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_R) player.setScratching();
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_F) player.setFiring();
}

public void keyReleased(int k) {
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) player.setLeft(false);
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) player.setRight(false);
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_UP) player.setUp(false);
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) player.setDown(false);
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_W) player.setJumping(false);
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_E) player.setGliding(false);
}

}
```

this is the part i need help with:

```
          ActionListener actListner = new ActionListener()    {           
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {               
             cnt += 1;               
             g.drawString("Counter = "+cnt, 120, 120);               
          }              
      };         
       Timer timer = new Timer(1000, actListner);            
       timer.start();
```

Can anyone help me? I just can't get it to stop refreshing and it won't remove the milliseconds either.

Thank you in advance

P.S.

I have a feeling the first second runs way slower than the others.

P.P.S.: i have looked at "how to implement timers" but none of those worked and I found this one on a website that doesn't return an error.

Comment: You are newing-up your timer every time `Level1State.Draw(g);` is called.  My guess is this is the "refreshing".  I'm failing to see where in code you would even notice the milliseconds and why it's an issue.  Can you clarify what you mean by removing the milliseconds?

Comment: Well for example: it shows the following on my screen. 15196 = 15 seconds. 14206 = 14 seconds and that stuff. i want to remoev those last couple of digits. I see how I draw that string so it recycles everytime but I have no Idea how to change it. this is what i need: A timer that counts up and at a certain point it stops. ( i know how to do this myself) All you need to do is a normal timer that uses the g.drawString to get it on the screen and I can't find anywhere how.